# How To use touch listener in this case

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, drawable, android-drawable

I want help in this
Anyways, I'm trying to achieve a button press with an `ImageView`. What I want is, `ImageView` to display a default image, and if pressed (`OnTouch`) [which has a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` block] to run a frame animation. When youi release the touch [which has a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` block], it should stop the animation and return to the default image.

Note: Frame animation is continuous repeating, and should not include the default image as one of the looped through image. (Button up image should not be displayed when touching)

Now the problem is, I have the animation working, but as per the android documentation, the first item in the `` tag will be displayed by default. But if I add the default image (button un-touched state) as the first item, it will be displayed in the loop. Also, when I release the touch, I use `stop()` method of the `AnimationDrawable`, which stops the animation at the current frame (image) and I can't seem to find any way to stop and go to default image state.

Here is my code:

button_anim.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_press1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_press2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_press3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_anim);
    buttonAnim = (AnimationDrawable)button.getBackground();
    button.setOnTouchListener(buttonTest);
}
private OnTouchListener buttonTest = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            buttonAnim.start();
            // Log.d("Test", "Touch down");
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            buttonAnim.stop();
            // Log.d("Test", "Touch Stop");
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Default image:- button1_inactive.png

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution is to **reassign** the default image **after stopping**, so:

```
...
else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        buttonAnim.stop();
        button.setBackgroundResource( /** Assign again here the default image */ );
    }
...
```

Replace the **"Assign again here the default image"** comment with your default image identifier or drawable.

And logically, assign again R.drawable.button_anim into the button when on touch down, before starting the animation again.